# Is there any significance to 1.21 GW?

Tags: power, lightning

In connection with a [related question on Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15825/in-back-to-the-future-why-the-energy-to-travel-in-time-was-1-21-gwatts) Stack Exchange page: does this number 1.21 GW make any sense? What is 1.21 GWatts? With what can you compare it? Can the [lightning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning) really produce this amount of [power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_%28physics%29)?

Are there any idea of why this number was used in a physical sense?

Comment: Thanks for edit, but isn't important say this 1.21 GW is about the film Back to the Future?

Comment: Note that Watts is power, not energy and that short enough time scales can mean that high power *does not* imply a lot of energy (see for example sub-nanosecond pulsed lasers).

Comment: There is no reason, it just sounded nice. It's probably taken by dividing the energy released in a lightning stroke and dividing by the time of the flash, so it is probably a roughly accurate amount of power in the lightning.

Comment: @Rodrigo: no, not for asking about it in a physics context. In any case, most people will probably either recognize the source of the number or click through to the question on SFF.

Comment: this site says that "jiggawatts" is the mispronunciation for gigawatt...funny... www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jiggawatt

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but I see no issue with the question. Yes, the reference is to the movie Back to the Future, but he's asking about real world physiscs. I upvoted it back.

Comment: Answered by the film's writer/creator; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/196566/20774

Answer (score 4):

There is no deep reason, it just sounded nice (the one-two-one number-palindrome plus the techie sounding mispronounciation "jigga-watts"). It's a number taken by dividing the energy released in a lightning stroke (a few million joules according to Wikipedia) and dividing by the time of the flash (in the millisecond range), so that the total power is in the billions of Watts. It is not the absurdly precise value of 1.21 GW given in the movie, however.

Comment: It's not a mispronunciation. The giga prefix is considered to be correctly pronounced with either a hard or soft initial "g". In fact, the US National Bureau of Standards Special Publication 304A issued 1968 specified the pronunciation with a soft initial "g" as "ji-ga".